# SharedPreferences is never null even when empty

Tags: javascript, android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to toast "No user saved" when the login button is clicked and the SharedPreferences has nothing saved in it. But when I use this code, it always proceeds to the else statement even if SharedPreferences is empty:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (preferences == null){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No user saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
```

**MY_PREFS.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map />
```

Is there a better way to write the if-statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you obtain `SharedPreferences` instance app will create empty file, so it will always exists and won't be `null`, as you may call then `edit()` and put some initial data in it. But before modifying this file you can check which keys are already inside

```
Map<String, ?> storedValues = preferences.getAll();
int numberOfStoredValues = storedValues.size();
```

`numberOfStoredValues` will be obviusly `0` when there is nothing stored in it (yet). so your `if` should look like below

```
if (preferences.getAll().size() == 0)
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No user saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

note that you can also check that some particular key already exists in these preferences, e.g. login is stored

```
if (preferences.contains(KEY_LOGIN))
```